# how do we take whole paragraph as a input in 2d array as separate lines?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have to take few lines a input into a 2d array , each line on new row until a line is equal to "......." .

I am able to take words in  each row but taking line as an input is creating an error.

SAMPLE INPUT :

> ```
>    1)I love you.
>    2)You love me.
>    3)We're a happy family.
>    4).......
> ```

CODE:

```
        char arr[10][100];
        int i = 0 ;
        int j  ;
        char limit[] = ".......";
        do
        {  
            j = 0 ;
            while(arr[i][j] != '\0')
            {
                scanf("%c" , &arr[i][j]);
                j = j + 1;
            }

            i = i + 1 ;
        }
        while(strcmp(limit  , &arr[i-1][0]) != 0);
```

[image: Error as soon as I press enter to move to next line]

Comment: C++ or C? Pick one or both of the communities are going to throw tomatoes.

Comment: You access to memory beyond `arr[10]` with `i`, you're condition `while(strcmp(limit  , &arr[i-1][0]) != 0);` is not good.

Comment: You are testing the value of `arr[i][j]` before you have set it.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use `fgets()` which scans till newline char is found.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {

        char arr[10][100];
        int i = 0 ;
        char limit[] = ".......";
        do
        {  
            fgets(arr[i], 100, stdin);              //Use fgets() instead of scanning char by char

            char *pos;
            if ((pos=strchr(arr[i], '\n')) != NULL)     //Remove the trailing '\n' in the string
               *pos = '\0';

            i = i + 1;
        }
        while(strcmp(limit, arr[i - 1]) != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to do like this :

```
    char arr[10][100];
    int i = 0 ;
    int j  ;
    char limit[] = ".......";
    do
    {  
        scanf("%99s", &arr[i][0], 100);
        i = i + 1 ;
    }
    while(strcmp(limit  , &arr[i-1][0]) != 0);
```